# is there a way that the bootstrap modal opens first before a new tab opens?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The code below will open the new tab first before the bootstrap modal appears. Is there a way that the bootstrap modal opens first before the new tab?

```
$(document).on("click", ".listings", function() {
     var id =  $(this).attr("id");

     $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.myjson.com/bins/2sadq?pretty=1",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {

            var modal = "<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'><div class='modal-dialog' role='document'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Aloha!</h4></div><div class='modal-body'>Apartment address through Google Maps. Epic! Right?</div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div>";
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $(".modals").append(modal);

            var selectedApartment = $.grep(response.apartments, function(apartment) {
                return apartment.id == id;
            });

            var address = selectedApartment[0].address;

            window.open("http://maps.google.com/?q=" + address);
        },

        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    });
});
```

Also, if you want to look at the full project file, here's the dropbox link.

[Full project file dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0eqrqa97gx10bmp/AACqLTt-grFfUak50p71pEvVa?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also setTimeout to delay the open-popup:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.open("http://maps.google.com/?q=" + address)}, 1000);
```

Update: In case you want the popup appears after you click the close button:

```
success: function(response) {

                var modal = "<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'><div class='modal-dialog' role='document'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Aloha!</h4></div><div class='modal-body'>Apartment address through Google Maps. Epic! Right?</div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div>";

                $(".modals").html(modal);

                var selectedApartment = $.grep(response.apartments, function(apartment) {
                    return apartment.id == id;
                });

                var address = selectedApartment[0].address;

                $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    window.open("http://maps.google.com/?q=" + address);
                });
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
```

Comment: This works.  I just wonder, is it possible that the new tab will only open if I hit the close button on the modal?

Comment: I just notice also that the modal won't work on first call or click. Why is it?

Comment: Wow it's perfect now! Why did you use .html() rather than .append() method? And which code fix the modal not working on first call?

Comment: **1.** When you use append(), many modals will be added so you have many duplicated modals. **2.** You have to call _$('#myModal').modal('show')_ after _$(".modals").html(modal), because the modal now is a true element in the DOM. In your code, you had called modal show before it became a true element.

Comment: Got it. Do you have any recommendations on how to improve my understanding on  third-party documentations like bootstrap and jquery?